# Android how to play video using VLC Player?

Tags: android, video-streaming

I have app for play video in android like as

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vlcforandroid.vlcdirectprofree&hl=en

I want to integrate this app in my app. I have Url for video Streaming and i want to open this video in this app(Vlc Direct), Any idea?

I open this app using:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
            i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.vlcdirect.vlcdirect");
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            startActivity(i);
```

But how it start with video streaming, Or any other Player for video Streaming?

Comment: There is a bug in the VLC player for android, I have the same problem , and found someone else alreay post this in the bug list of vlc.org, but in new version of 2.0.6, the bug is still not fixed! vlc.org give the example code for call vlc app by intent, but it can not work with http or ftp at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More like,

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vlcdirect.vlcdirect", "com.vlcdirect.vlcdirect.URLStreamerActivity"));
i.putExtra("url", url);
startActivity(i);
```

Which supposes that the component, activity, and payload are as shown, and also that the activity is explicitly or implicitly exported -- *I don't know the actual values, or if the activity is exported*. vlcdirect doesn't document this, but you can

1. ask the developer, or
2. view the log as you stream from a URL within that app, to identify the component and activity; dedex and decompile the .apk, to confirm the payload; duplicate payload classes, if necessary; give up and fume after the developer ignores you, if the activity is not exported.

Ideally you would broadcast a "view the stream from this URL" intent, and vlcdirect or any other suitable app would pick it up, but I don't know if vlcdirect or any other app respond to such.

Comment: in answer second line what is com.vlcdirect.vlcdirect.URLStreamerActivity

Comment: @Samir,  a guess, as I said. You need to determine the actual name of the activity.

Comment: how i check activity of vlcdirect?

Comment: @Samir, I suggested one way: view a stream in vlcdirect, and then check the system log with adb logcat, or the Catlog app on the market. You'll see the intent that started the activity that played the video -- but not its payload.

Comment: thnx,But cant play video....source ..  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vlcdirect.vlcdirect", "com.vlcdirect.vlcdirect.VLCDirect"));
  i.putExtra("url", "http:/www.tnp.sg/fk/lionscheers//test/MOV00675.3gp");
  startActivity(i);

Comment: hello if put url in put extra ,But how VLCDirect know this its play video using url ,I mean VLCDirect have check bundle for "url" tag .

Comment: @Samir, this is a third question from you that I addressed in my original answer. Please make an effort to understand what's already been said.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7621/discussion-between-samir-and-julian-fondren)

Comment: i effort so hard but cant give final solution

Answer (score 3):

VLC needs to be explicitly told the type:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setPackage("org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon");
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://ip:8080"), "video/h264");
startActivity(i);
```

i.e. just "video/*" wouldn't work for me

Comment: if you use setClass `org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity` then you can drop the mime info.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answers didn't work me. After a bit of searching I found [the official docs here](https://wiki.videolan.org/Android_Player_Intents/).

Basically, here it is:

```
int vlcRequestCode = 42; //request code used when finished playing, not necessary if you only use startActivity(vlcIntent)
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///storage/emulated/0/Movies/KUNG FURY Official Movie.mp4"); //your file URI
 Intent vlcIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 vlcIntent.setPackage("org.videolan.vlc");
 vlcIntent.setDataAndTypeAndNormalize(uri, "video/*");
 vlcIntent.putExtra("title", "Kung Fury");
 vlcIntent.putExtra("from_start", false);
 vlcIntent.putExtra("subtitles_location", "/sdcard/Movies/Fifty-Fifty.srt"); //subtitles file
 startActivityForResult(vlcIntent, vlcRequestCode);
```

You can remove unnecessary parts for you.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me.. thanks!